# Are there web3.js-like in Cardano?

Tags: decentralized-applications

With the Cardano's Alonzo Hard fork coming, the Cardano testnet will be coming in. I assumed that there is a frontend library for interacting with the Cardano testnet, however I couldn't find anywhere. I wonder if there are libraries that are being developed?

Regards,

Ivan

Answer (score 3):

The only JavaScript library there is right now, is the [cardano-serialization-lib](https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib) developer by Emurgo.

However, as already mentioned, there is a number of Catalyst proposals that you might want to vote for in the upcoming rounds:

- Fund4: [JavaScript SDK for Blockfrost API](https://cardano.ideascale.com/a/dtd/JavaScript-SDK-for-Blockfrost-API/341442-48088) (pardon my shameless plug, we're the team behind [Blockfrost.io](https://blockfrost.io/) API)
- Fund4: [Ouroboros Networking Lib in JS](https://cardano.ideascale.com/a/dtd/Ouroboros-Networking-Lib-in-JS/342248-48088)
- Fund5: [Cardano JS API](https://cardano.ideascale.com/a/dtd/Cardano-JS-API/350707-48088)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a Javascript library, but it looks like the Cardanoscan folks are building one for interfacing with the Cardano blockchain ([link to article](https://adapulse.io/building-a-ouroborus-networking-package-for-javascript-developers/)).

The current pioneer's testnet for writing smart contracts uses Plutus. You can read more about this [here](https://docs.cardano.org/projects/plutus/en/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

We have https://meshjs.dev/ and https://lucid.spacebudz.io/ now as javascript libraries for Web3 development on Cardano